# Need to limit my results to one row when connected to another table with multiple rows

Tags: sql

Table1

```
SaleID  |  Name  
123     |  John Doe
456     |  Jane Doe
```

Table2

```
SaleID  |  ProductID    |  ProductCost  |  ProductSize
123     |  1            |  $200         |  Medium
123     |  2            |  $250         |  Large
123     |  3            |  $100         |  Small
```

Results:

```
SaleID     |  Name         | Product1Cost | Product1Size  | Product2Cost | Product2Size   | Product3Cost  | Product3Size
123        |  John Doe     | $200         | Medium
123        |  John Doe     |              |               | $250         | Large            
123        |  John Doe     |              |               |                               | $100          | Small
```

Expected Results:

```
SaleID    |  Name        | Product1Cost  | Product1Size | Product2Cost  | Product2Size | Product3Cost  | Product3Size
123       |  John Doe    | $200          | Medium       | $250          | Large        | $100          | Small
```

Here is my query:

```
Select    
    SaleID    = a.SaleID,
    Name = a.Name,
    Product1Cost = case when b.ProductID = '1'then b.Product1Cost end,
    Product1Size = case when b.ProductID = '1'then b.Product1Size end,
    Product2Cost = case when b.ProductID = '2'then b.Product2Cost end,
    Product2Size = case when b.ProductID = '2'then b.Product2Size end,
    Product3Cost = case when b.ProductID = '3'then b.Product3Cost end,
    Product3Size = case when b.ProductID = '3'then b.Product3Size end



from Table1 a

    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM Table2 b
        where a.SaleID = b.SaleID        
    ) b
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `apply` for this.  A `join` and `group by` should work:

```
Select a.SaleID, a.Name,
       Product1Cost = max(case when b.ProductID = '1' then b.Product1Cost end),
       Product1Size = max(case when b.ProductID = '1' then b.Product1Size end),
       Product2Cost = max(case when b.ProductID = '2' then b.Product2Cost end),
       Product2Size = max(case when b.ProductID = '2' then b.Product2Size end),
       Product3Cost = max(case when b.ProductID = '3' then b.Product3Cost end),
       Product3Size = max(case when b.ProductID = '3' then b.Product3Size end)
from Table1 a join
     Table2 b
     on a.SaleID = b.SaleID        
group by a.SaleID, a.Name;
```

You don't need to do `name = a.name`.  The default alias *is* the column name.

Also, if `ProductId` is a number, then don't put single quotes around the comparison.  Instead of `= '1'`, use `= 1`.

Comment: This was just an example i created.  The view actually has different names, so that is why I used name = a.name.  Also, tried the group by and it didn't work.  Do i have to add each field to the group by clause?  I have over 200 fields.

Comment: @JPrice . . . The `group by` should work as written in the answer.  Note that use of `sum()` for all the columns not in the `group by`.